# How to add a listener to the plus and minus buttons on a NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

How do you add a listener to the plus and minus buttons on a NumberPicker?

I am aware that there is [onValueChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener.html) however the problem I have using this is whenever you are scrolling through the picker (instead of using the plus | minus button) each item in the list fires the change event. I cannot use that because whenever something is selected I query a database & it causes a small but noticeable lag.

Scroll listener

```
manufacturer.setOnScrollListener(new android.widget.NumberPicker.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChange(android.widget.NumberPicker numberPicker, 
                int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == android.widget.NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Value listener

```
manufacturer.setOnValueChangedListener(new android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

            Log.e("app",""+newVal);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't even run a db query with the more/minus listener that doesn't exists actually.

Comment: Even so I would still like to know how to have a value listener that isn't fired by scrolling through the items (or at least one that filters out events caused by scrolling).

Comment: That `Listener` doesn't exists as I said before, you could make your own datepicker or may be you could try to `Override` the existing one but I don't think overriding it would let you to add the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't the onScrollListener be called after the button is clicked anyway if it causes a change in the display?

Comment: No it doesn't its only fired for scrolling events